# Get only CSS value of particular Tailwind CSS class

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

Is there a way to get only the CSS value of a Tailwind CSS class? For example, if I have `translate-x-4` tailwind class I want only the `1rem` CSS value [(since class `translate-x-4` is `--tw-translate-x: 1rem;`)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/translate). This would be pretty useful with [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/), because framer motion animation object can accept a wide variety of CSS values like `1rem`, `#ff3322`. Is there some kind of way to do something like this `<motion.div animate={{ x: getValue('translate-x-4') }} initial={false} />`.

I know there exists [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro) but it "returns" entire Tailwind CSS class. Is there a similar utility for getting only the value?

Answer (score 1):

I think [xwind](https://github.com/Arthie/xwind) is what you are looking for.

```
import xw from "xwind";

const styles = xw`text-red-100 hover:text-green-100 hover:bg-blue-200`;
// OR (with custom array syntax)
const styles = xw`text-red-100 hover[text-green-100 bg-blue-200]`;
```

Xwind converts your tailwind classes into Postcss-js / JSS compatible syntax.
Something like this:

```
const styles = {
  "--text-opacity": "1",
  color: ["#fde8e8", "rgba(253, 232, 232, var(--text-opacity))"],
  "&:hover": {
    "--text-opacity": "1",
    "--bg-opacity": "1",
    color: ["#def7ec", "rgba(222, 247, 236, var(--text-opacity))"],
    backgroundColor: ["#c3ddfd", "rgba(195, 221, 253, var(--bg-opacity))"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and enable extension [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/intellisense). This way, when you hover over any tailwind classes you can see the complete CSS.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I use it too, but I need the value of a Tailwind CSS class in my code so the motion.div component can animate. The extension only shows the CSS class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

TailwindCSS has a function called `resolveConfig` that returns an object of the generated values. The theme attribute stores the css values. I used this in my React app as follows (at the top of my file):

```
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";

const styleConfig = resolveConfig().theme;
```

`styleConfig` then is an object with things like backgroundColor, gap, etc.